# Python - Relation between variables

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, data-science, correlation

i have a csv table that looks like this:

[image]

Table data:

```
rows = [['0', 'False', 'False', '0'], 
['1', 'False', 'False', '0'], 
['2', 'True', 'False', '80'], 
['3', 'False', 'False', '80'], 
['4', 'False', 'False', '80'], 
['5', 'False', 'False', '80']]

fields= ['id', 'i1', 'i2', 'm1']
```

The table has over 1000 rows. There are obviously dependencies in the table. For example, m1 has the value 80 as soon as i1 becomes true.

What are the possibilities in Python to identify these dependencies? I have already tried the corr function - unfortunately I get a correlation of 0.0025 for m1 and i1

```
dat = pd.read_csv(data.csv)
dat.head(5)
corr = dat.corr()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmpa(corr, cmap="Greens", annot=True)
```

The correlation between i1 and m1 0.0025.

Comment: Please add your dataset as a copyable string, not as an image

Comment: *For example, m1 has the value 80 as soon as i1 becomes true* - so you mean this is a time series?

Comment: The correlation between i1 and m1 is low because there are probably just a few samples that satisfies i1=True (relatively to any other sample with other condition than i1=True)